# Loop in Excel 2013

Tags: excel, loops, vba

I am having problems with getting a loop to run.

I have a Source1 spreadsheet with a list of values in Column A on the CC's tab. Each number is to be copied individually into Cell B1 on the Template tab of the Source2 spreadsheet. 
Cell B1 triggers a consolidation of information (mainly indexed info) and displays it in a template - an aggregate picture of lots of background data. I then Copy A1:K71, and paste this into the Output tab of the Source1 spreadsheet.

I want to work down the list in Column A of the CC's tab, and append each output from the Source2 spreadsheet into the Output tab automatically.

I have the copy/paste working, but I am having problems with the loop.

```
Selection.Copy
Windows("Source2.xlsx").Activate
Range("B1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A1:K71").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Source1.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Ouput").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
  ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=ActiveCell
```

Comment: What loop? I don't see no loop. Please show your attempt at solving your problem so that we can help you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

@Andrew, after reading and re-reading your question, I don't think a loop of any kind is necessary. The macro-recorder results you gave above provide information about how you can solve this. I tested this by creating a Source1 Workbook with values placed in column A on a sheet labeled CC's. I also added a sheet labeled Output. Then, I opened a second Workbook with a sheet labeled Template. Here is the sub-procedure I used to produce the result I think you are describing above:

```
 Sub AndrewProject()
 '    COMMENT: Declare variables used throughout this procedure
      Dim InitialVals As Range
      Dim OutputVals As Range
      Dim FinalResults As Range
      Dim FinalOutput As Range
      Dim cell As Variant

 '    COMMENT: Set the range objects so they are easier to manipulate
      Set InitialVals = Workbooks("Source1").Worksheets("CC's").Range("A2:A72")
      Set OutputVals = Workbooks("Source2").Worksheets("Template").Range("B2:B72")
      Set FinalResults = Workbooks("Source2").Worksheets("Template").Range("A2:K72")
      Set FinalOutput = Workbooks("Source1").Worksheets("Output").Range("A2:K72")

 '    COMMENT: This line copies the values in Source1 Workbook and pastes them into Source2 Workbook
      InitialVals.Copy
      OutputVals.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
 '    COMMENT: Additional code goes here to create the desired output. To simplify things, I put a
 '    function in Source2, column K that concatenates the string "Output" with InitialVals copied
 '    from Source1. To emulate your Source2 Template, I placed random values between 1 and 1000 in
 '    Cells A2:A72 and C2:J72.

 '    COMMENT: Copy the FinalResults from Source2 "Template" tab into the Source1 "Output" tab
      FinalResults.Copy
      FinalOutput.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
 End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Andy, Many thanks for having a look at this. I tried as you suggested, but I think my explanation is at fault.

Comment: Hi Andy, Many thanks for having a look at this. I tried as you suggested, but I think my explanation is at fault. Your suggestion results in me doing a copy and paste the entire Source1 CC's list into both spreadsheets.                                                                                             For my purposes, Source1 CC's tab has a list of numeric values. The list can be between 20 and 1000 lines. Source2 is a template where the Source1 value is put into cell B1. This then populates the template with information that i then copy and paste back into the Output tab on Source1.

Comment: I need each template copy to be appended to the bottom of the prior one. The small script I wrote allows me to do what I need, but only one entry at a time. Given some of the volumes I have to do, it needs to be more automated that I have currently.

Comment: @Andrew, your additional explanation helps. I'll take another look see if I can help you automate it. Be back soon.

Comment: Hi again Andy, sorry I was away yesterday. The looks to work to a degree, but I am still experiencing some issues. It might be my lack of understanding rather than the script. The output results in the list from Src1CC being pasted into B1 Src2Template and then part of the template being copied into Src1Output.

Comment: I wish I knew how to do this stuff... anyway. Src1CC is a list that needs to be input one at a time into Cell B1 in the Src2Template. This then activates the background information of Cells A1 to K72, I copy these and then paste them into Src1Output. Each time a new value goes into B1, I take a copy of the Src2Template and append it to the bottom of the previous copied information. I think the loop needs to go on the Src1CC. I also need to loop the copy into Src1Output to ensure that all output of the values of Src1CC are displayed.

Comment: Are you saying that a single input from Source1 will have 720 different calculations in Source2Template, which you are calling "background information"? So if A1=32, then Source2Template will do 720 calculations that depend on the input 32. Then, A2 will do the same thing on a new value. If you have 70 input values from Source1, then you will ultimately be doing 50,400 calculations in Source1Output? I thought you were saying that a single value would only calculate values in that row, so that if A1 =32, then Source2 does 10 or 11 calculations.

Comment: Hi Andy, almost. eg - If in Source1 A1=32, then 32 gets copied into B1 on Source2Template (where all calculations are done), calling information from other spreadsheets onto the Source2Template. I copy the Source2Template(A1:K72) into the Source1Output, then move to Source1 A2, and repeat the process. Source1Ouput will have the information appended when pasting, so if there are 10 values in Source1, then all these values will have the information from Source2Template in this tab. I am playing with costcentres, FTE and activity, which is why I have to do each one separately and then amalgamate.

Comment: So where are formulas in the Source2 Template Worksheet? Are they completely surrounding the B1 in Source2, where you are pasting A1=32? So in Source2, Range("A1:A72") are formulas, Range("B2:B72") have formulas, and Range("C1:K72") are formulas?

Answer (score 0):

OK @Andrew...this has got to be my last attempt. I believe this answers your question.

```
Sub AutomateIt()
'   Declare your variables
    Dim cell         As Range
    Dim Src1CC       As Range
    Dim Src2Template As Range
    Dim Src2Calcs    As Range
    Dim Src1Output   As Range
    Dim NextRow      As Long
    Dim count        As Integer

'   Set the ranges so they can be manipulated
    Set Src1CC = Workbooks("Source1").Worksheets("CC").Range("A1")
    Set Src2Template = Workbooks("Source2").Worksheets("Template").Range("B1")
    Set Src2Calcs = Workbooks("Source2").Worksheets("Template").Range("A1:K72")
    Set Src1Output = Workbooks("Source1").Worksheets("Output").Range("A1:K72")
    Src2Template.ClearContents
    count = 0

'   Loop through all the cells and calculate stuff
    For Each cell In Src1CC.Range(Src1CC, Src1CC.End(xlDown))
        'Determine the next empty row (plus a space for readability)
        NextRow = Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 2

        'Send a copy of the Src1CC cell value to the Src2Template
        cell.Copy Src2Template

        'Re-calculate A1:K72 based on cell value
        Src2Calcs.Calculate

        'Copy Src2Calcs results and paste to Source1 Output
        Src2Calcs.Copy
        Src1Output.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        count = count + 1
        MsgBox "You have pasted " & count & " results."

        'Change Src1Output Range so that the next paste is the next blank row 
        'plus one additional row for readability.
        Set Src1Output = Workbooks("Source1").Worksheets("Output").Range(Cells(NextRow, 1), Cells(NextRow, 11))
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Andy, many thanks for your patience. I think it will work with a tweak, which again is due to my lack of understanding rather than your code. Your line       Set Src1Output = Workbooks("test").Worksheets("Output").Range(Cells(NextRow, 1), Cells(NextRow, 11))
    Next cell looks for the next available empty row, however I need the appended copies to be placed after

Comment: Next cell looks for the next available empty row, however I need the appended copies to be placed after the last line of the template, which is a constant of 65 lines. because your command finds empty lines within the template, it falls over. Again this is my lack of knowledge of the topic.

Comment: Well...hopefully, I've given you a head start. I can no longer devote time to this project, but I'm sure if you use the Macro Recorder as your guide, you can learn the main objects, properties, and methods to achieve your goal. Your description leads me to believe that you are 90% there and with a little time and patience, you will solve it.